# How to extract link from a string using regex patterns in java?

Tags: java, regex

My String:

`download_recording true Package available http://abc.com/recDownload/635131586215948750.exe`

How to get `http://abc.com/recDownload/635131586215948750.exe` from the above string?

please help

Answer (score 3):

This blog conatins sample code:

http://blog.houen.net/java-get-url-from-string/

As well as this question:

[Detect and extract url from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713558/detect-and-extract-url-from-a-string)

And this might help as well:

[How to detect the presence of URL in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string)

Comment: For the first one, you should extract sufficient information from the link to make the answer self-contained (not dependent on checking the link), since links die. For the other two, comments or flagging it as a duplicate would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple one to match things that include a prefixed protocol.
`[a-z]+:\/\/[^ \n]*`

```java
Pattern.compile("[a-z]+:\/\/[^ \n]*").matcher(
    "download_recording true Package available http://abc.com/recDownload/635131586215948750.exe click the link"
).find();
//"http://abc.com/recDownload/635131586215948750.exe"
```

---

Equivalent javascript

```
'download_recording true Package available http://abc.com/recDownload/635131586215948750.exe click the link'
    .match(/[a-z]+:\/\/[^ \n]*/)
```

Comment: I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression) to get some java. The `find()` method won't return you a `String` directly

Answer (score 0):

Simple use of the split method from the string class should parse this.

```
String s = "download_recording true Package available http://abc.com/recDownload/635131586215948750.exe";
//We now have the values on either side of where http:// was
String[] splitted = s.split("http://");
//so index 1 is the url and we can just append http:// back on the beginning to get the whole url
String url = "http://" + splitted[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex is what you are looking for:

`(http\:\/\/){0,1}(www){0,1}[\.]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)*`