# Filter urls from text using Java

Tags: java, url

I have text stored in a database and I want to filtered the urls that the text contain. How is it possible to filter the urls from text using Java code. For example I have the following text inside my db `"The dress-a-likes! Try to look normal and this is what happens.  @ Bar Louie http://t.co/sNVcoqT0Bc"`. How can I filtered the link `http://t.co/sNVcoqT0Bc.`

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://.*|www\\..*");
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(cursor.next().get("text"));

         Matcher m = p.matcher("http://...");
}
```

How can I filtered the cursor.next().get("text") with the matcher. Cursor... is an object while matcher waiting for a String. How can I convert that object to String?

Comment: you can use `indexOf()`

Comment: Search for known URI schemes and then read everything til the next whitespace.

Comment: Will you have the link at the end of the text only ? If yes you can use indexOf. If no you can do what @Tom has suggested above

Comment: How using like `str.substring(str.indexOf("http"));` if the url is ever at the end of the main string?

Comment: No this is just an example. Basically the text I have stored in my db is tweets from twitter.

Comment: @FereRes what is the patter of text .give more examples

Comment: Is tweets from twitter, I want to filter the links from all the tweets I have stored in my db.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713558/detect-and-extract-url-from-a-string

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I tried. However, how can I be sure that I  ve got all the urls using http?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to locate where the "http://" and then take te whole string until the end.

Use: `int indexOf(String str)`

If there is the posibility of having something more after the URL, then locate the space using another indexOf().

Now use: `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` where fromIndex should be the index finded before.

Make a substring from one of the index until the other.

Use: `string substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

Answer (score 3):

Try using ANTLR to parse your file. Create a simple grammar that extracts the links alone. the links end when there is a space character " ".
This will parse your whole file and returns all the URL (if there are more than one).