# Android - Get specific text from TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to get specific value inside a `TextView`, namely Youtube link.

I want to extract only the link from for example a `TextView` which contains "Check this out! (Youtube link here)". "Check this out! " needs to be omitted and only obtain the Youtube link. The `TextView` is user inputted, so it varies.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You have to get the entire text of the text view, and then parse it.  If it always starts with "Check this out!" that's easy-  just skip ahead that many letters.  If its more variable you'll need to look into regular expressions or other custom work.

Comment: You might find [setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) useful.

Comment: I got the entire text of `TextView` using `return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();`. The problem is, "Check this out! " is just an example.. It is user typed and it can and will change according to the user.. I've gotten the Regex but don't know how to apply it to get the Youtube link..

Comment: How is `setTag` useful?

Comment: can you please paste the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method from [@BullyWiiPlaza answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28269120/4848308)

```
public static String extractYouTubeUrl(String text)
{
    String urlRegex = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher urlMatcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    while (urlMatcher.find())
    {
       String url = text.substring(urlMatcher.start(0),
                urlMatcher.end(0))
       if(url.contains("youtube.com")
        return url;
    }    
    return "";
}
```

How to use it:

```
String stringWithYouTubeUrl = tvWithYouTubeUrl.getText().toString();
String youTubeUrl = extractYouTubeUrl(stringWithYouTubeUrl);

Log.d(TAG, "youTubeUrl is" + youTubeUrl);
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I'm using it in onBindViewHolder method inside `RecyclerView` which is void which means I can't use `return url`.. Out of desperation, I did `if(url.contains("youtube.com"))
                        youtubeVidUrl = url;` but as expected, it says `youtubeVidUrl` might not have been initialized..

Comment: Or.. Getting each value of the list till it ends, it's impactful on performance though..

Comment: Umm please could you provide your `RecyclerView` so we can help you better...I'll edit my answer to fit your needs

Comment: Modified stuffs from your link, basic is still the same, extract URLs, and then check whether the URLs contains youtube or not, and if it has, get the URL.. Thanks! :D

Comment: Glad to have this problem fixed (bugs may remain though) in only about an hour hahaha! :D

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular expressions with the `Patterns.WEB_URL` regular expression to find all urls in your text.

Comment: I have regex for Youtube link, how to apply it? I know how to match it, but to get only the value of matched Regex eludes me..

Comment: You can first filter  Patterns.WEB_URL and check the
link contains of youtube keyword

Comment: Your answer helped me to get close to the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
String textViewStr = "Check this out! (Youtube link)";
int pos_1 = textViewStr.indexOf('(');
int pos_2 = textViewStr.indexOf(')');

String result = textViewStr.substring(pos_1+1,pos_2);
System.out.println(result); // print: Youtube link
```

**UPDATE**:

```
String textViewStr = "asdf Check this out! https://www.youtube.com/ asdg asfgf https:!!";
String [] arrStr = textViewStr.split(" ");
String regex = "/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=‌​|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/g";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.DOTALL);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < arrStr.length ; ++i){
            Matcher m = m = p.matcher(arrStr[i]);
            if ( m.matches() )
                Log.d("Matcher", "PATTERN MATCHES! " + arrStr[i]);
            else
                Log.d("MATCHER", "PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH! : " + arrStr[i]);
        }
```

This print:

```
D/MATCHER: PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH! : asdf
D/MATCHER: PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH! : Check
D/MATCHER: PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH! : this
D/MATCHER: PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH! : out!
D/Matcher: PATTERN MATCHES! https://www.youtube.com/
D/MATCHER: PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH! : asdg
D/MATCHER: PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH! : asfgf
D/MATCHER: PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH! : https:!!s
```

Comment: `String textViewStr = "Check this out! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxX0a8UdjuI";`  now just find the HTTPS position it may solve right? @KevinMurvie

Comment: @KevinMurvie See the update. You can't search https because this: "https is a secure protocol. see the https at https:////www.youtube.com/...."

Comment: This is my regex /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/g

Comment: You change the "String regex" by your regex string and this should work. Check the answer edit. It is not necessary the while on strings that are urls.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube link syntax is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<value>`. what you really need is `v=<value>`. just search whole string for "`watch?`" if there is `v=` after that then just take the value and create the whole url from it.

Comment: I got the value if the `TextView` contains only Youtube link by using a method called `extractYoutubeId` from an answer in SO

Comment: use String.indexOf("watch?"); to get the index of "watch?" in the whole string. then check if there is v= after it, if it does then just get the value after "=".