# Splitting a string that contains url/link in java

Tags: java, string, split

Supposing we have a string that contains some text in the beggining and at the end of the string there is a url/link e.x. http://www.google.com . What is the best way to split this string in 2 variables : 
DescriptionTxt , LinkTxt

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some example inputs and their respective outputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect and extract url from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713558/detect-and-extract-url-from-a-string)

Comment: It depends on the link pattern. Can you rely on the fact that it begins with http:// ?

Comment: Yes, I'm producing the urls so each of them is going to start with http . However , I don't want to lose the http pattern , at the beggining of the splitted text I'm going to create.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] results = mystring.split(indexOf("http"));
```

Then if you wanted two separate Strings,

```
String DescriptionTxt = results[0];
String LinkTxt = results[1];
```

Comment: For example : Initial String "Thanks Ben Arnao for your help http://www.stackoverflow.com" . The result is going to be likes this : (?) : results[0] = "Thanks Ben Arnao for your help" , results[1] ="http://www.stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Ok well this really depends on the format of your input and how you want your program to recognize the URL. If it's always going to be the last x number of characters in the string after a whitespace, you could use lastIndexOf(" ") as your delimiter instead

Comment: Thank you very much @Ben Arnao , I'm going to try this solution!

Comment: @Dimitris K why don't you upvote and accept his answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting patterns is always tricky. There might be URLs that contain the keywords you look for. For instance:

```
A short description http://my.foo.bar/http-is-a-protocol
```

If you go with lastIndexOf("http"), your parser will fail. A good solution can be much more complex that assumed in the first place. In an advanced algorithm you could go for `http://`, but `https://` is just as valid. And don't forget capital letters like `HTTP://`.

And is there a reason why `http://` would not occur in your description, as well?

You won't get a complete solution here for your problem. Try to cover most of the cases with moderate effort and make sure you know what to do when your algorithm fails for something you haven't expected.