# Extract especific URL from String in java

Tags: java, string, url

I have a String like this:

> .........e1.whatsapp.net..............>.ns1.p13.dynect..hostmaster.whatsapp.com.x:a>.......X..:....

And I need to extract the first URL:

> e1.whatsapp.net

I was trying with the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713558/detect-and-extract-url-from-a-string) but not working for me, maybe because the amount of dots. Maybe if I try with another pattern regex, but I know nothing about "regex".

Any sugestion?

Comment: why not starting learning regex then?

Comment: `hostmaster.whatsapp.com` is also URL. Is there any pattern for your URL ?

Comment: Try to temporarily replace >1 number of dots (`.`) by some character that's not in regex like `>` and apply the same regex removing `\\b(https?|ftp|file)://` since your URLs don't have https etc before the address.

Comment: the pattern can be any kind of URL, like: www.google.com, stackoverflow.com, https://github.com, asdf.ru, and etc.

the most important thing is the dots who separate the domain and the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below may help you to extract the email with using regex.

```
class StringSeperator {

  public static void main(String args[]){
    String urlString = ".........e1.whatsapp.net..............>.ns1.p13.dynect..hostmaster.whatsapp.com.x:a>.......X..:....";
    String array[] = urlString.split("\\.\\.+"); 
    System.out.println(array[1]);
  }
}
```

Here I use regex as `\\.\\.+` which means two or more dots. The string split using two or more dots.

If I further explain about regex. Here I use `\\.` for depicting the dot and use `+` for saying one or more occurrences of a dots. For more details about Java regex please follow below link.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm