# Modify regex to find URL in string with or without http prefix

Tags: regex

I am trying to detect URL inside another string. I got an answer from another SO. However, it does not work for a use case needed by us.

[Detect and extract url from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713558/detect-and-extract-url-from-a-string)

```
        URL_REGEX = "(?:^|[\\W])((ht|f)tp(s?):\\/\\/|www\\.)"
            + "(([\\w\\-]+\\.){1,}?([\\w\\-.~]+\\/?)*"
            + "[\\p{Alnum}.,%_=?&#\\-+()\\[\\]\\*$~@!:/{};']*)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(URL_REGEX, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);

        String str = "hello example.com";    // DOES NOT WORK 
        //str = "$ANY_WORD example.com $ANY_WORD_1";    // DOES NOT WORK 
        str = "hello http://example.com";    // WORKS
```

Can you please modify above regex work for `str = "hello example.com"` as well?

Input String can be a combination of many words and urls

Comment: only for hello or any other word before a URL?

Comment: @perreal any word before a URL or after. String can be a combination of many words and urls

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate question has two regex patterns for matching URL with or without `http(s)://` and `www.`. If you'd like, you can [combine the two together](https://regex101.com/r/zusawb/1) or [like this](https://regex101.com/r/zusawb/2) _with no capturing groups_.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get it why you started your regex by using Non-Capturing group if you are just searching within a normal string as you indicated. but..

It should work by removing `(?:^|[\\W])((ht|f)tp(s?):\\/\\/|www\\.)`

But you will be missing the hello unless you add [a-z-]{5}

And i mostly built and test my regular expression by using https://regexr.com/

Comment: It will not capture http:// in URL. I need it to work for substrings with both http and without http.

Comment: `((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\&\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]{3})` but that will take links with generic 3 last tld