# Open Hyperlinks of Textview in WebView Android

Tags: java, android, html, hyperlink, textview

The following is the text that I have to set in text view. I wanted to open webview on click of hyperlink. Rest of the text should not be clickable.

```
String value = "Check on this link: <a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>";                                
 binding.text.setText(value);

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textColorLink="@color/g_turquoise_blue" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-to-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Comment: @MohammedAlaa That one will open in browser. But I wanted to make the link open in webview.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you if i got you correct

```
yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "https://google.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE:**
Try this

```
/**
 * Returns a list with all links contained in the input
 */
public static List<String> extractUrls(String text)
{
    List<String> containedUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
    String urlRegex = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher urlMatcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    while (urlMatcher.find())
    {
        containedUrls.add(text.substring(urlMatcher.start(0),
                urlMatcher.end(0)));
    }

    return containedUrls;
}
```

Example:

```
List<String> extractedUrls = extractUrls("Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/ and here is another link http://www.google.com/ \n which is a great search engine");

for (String url : extractedUrls)
{
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

Prints:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
http://www.google.com/
```

source: [Detect and extract url from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713558/detect-and-extract-url-from-a-string)

Comment: Thank you. But I will have to get the hyperlink from textview.

Comment: But how do I know which url is clicked?

Comment: the method extractUrls returns the links.

Comment: we can get a list of url's but how to identify which url is clicked(first or second)?